# Clone text from several elements to an a href as a mailto subject

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append all the text in the `td` elements to the `a` element as the subject of the `mailto` link, but I can only get the first closest elements text. How do I make it so it retrieves the text from *all* the elements? If possible I would rather have the `a` link inside the `tbody` element instead of the `tr` wrapper.

HTML:

```
<tbody>
<tr class="row-2" role="row">
    <td class="column-1" tabindex="0" style="">2238221D2</td>
    <td class="column-2">HPINC</td>
    <td class="column-3">N7P47AA</td>
    <td class="column-4">HP USB 3.0 to Gigabit LAN Adapter</td>
    <td class="column-5" style="display: none;">#4.2</td>
    <td class="column-6" style="display: none;">16</td>
    <td class="column-7" style="display: none;">30</td>
    <td class="column-8" style="display: none;">52</td>
    <a class="mailme" href="mailto:test@test.com?subject=Product request&body=">mailtolink</a>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Script:

```
$('a.mailme').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + 
    $(this).closest('a.mailme').prev('td').text());
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*the first closest elements text*?"

Comment: I want all the strings in the td elements to be set as the subject of the mailto "HPINC" "N7P47AA" etc - right now it only retrieves the string from the first closets td element.

Comment: did you try .html() instead of .text()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost right, just select all td-tags, get the text and join the resulting array:

```
$('a.mailme').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + 
    $(this).closest('.row-2').children('td').slice(0,-1).map(function() {return $(this).html()}).get().join(','));
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/21873jcz/

**EDIT** My Solution will work if you fix your html code. a tags are not permitted within tr-tags. Only td or th elements are allowed. So please fix your html and it will work

Answer (score 1):

I found a few problems but here is what you want:

https://jsfiddle.net/uqswr2k3/

```js
var subject = "";
$(".row-2 td").each (function() {
  subject = subject + '-' + $(this).html();
}); 

$(".mailme").attr('href', 'mailto:test@test.com?subject=' + subject + '&body=');
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="row-2" role="row">
    <td class="column-1" tabindex="0" style="">2238221D2</td>
    <td class="column-2">HPINC</td>
    <td class="column-3">N7P47AA</td>
    <td class="column-4">HP USB 3.0 to Gigabit LAN Adapter</td>
    <td class="column-5" style="display: none;">#4.2</td>
    <td class="column-6" style="display: none;">16</td>
    <td class="column-7" style="display: none;">30</td>
    <td class="column-8" style="display: none;">52</td>
    <a class="mailme" href="">mailtolink</a>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Make sure the `tbody` has an outside table or it can cause issues with jQuery. You were setting the value of the subject to the current iteration and not collecting them all. I put a variable named `subject` to add each `td` cells' HTML content. I separated each value in the subject with a dash `-` to make it cleaner.